# Using load with data from cells

Tags: string, cells, matlab-load

In my code I'm trying to use load with entries from a cell, but it is not working. The portion of my code below produces a 3 dimensional array of strings. The strings represent the paths to file names.

```
for i = 1:Something
 for j = 1:Something Different
  for k = 1: Yet Something Something Different
    DataPath{j,k,i} = 'F:\blah\blah\blah\fileijk    %file changes based on i,j,and k       
  end
 end
end
```

In the next part of the code I want to use load to open the files using the path names defined in the code above. I do this using the code below.

```
Dummy = DataPath{l,(k-1)*TSRRange+m}; 
Data = load(Dummy);
```

The idea is for Dummy to take the string content out of DataPath so I can use it in load. By doing this I thought that Dummy would be defined as a string and not a cell, but this is not the case. How do I pull the string out of DataPath so I can use it with load? Thanks.

I have to load the data this way because the data is located in multiple folders. I can post more of the code if needed, but it is complex.

Comment: If `Dummy` is a cell then `DataPath` must have been built in a different way than what you've shown in your example code.

Comment: In any case, you can use `cell2mat(Dummy)` to obtain the string in the cell.

Comment: If `l`,`k`,`m`,`TSRRange` variables are scalar, and if you don't get dimension error, your 2nd part should work. The question is are you really assigning strings to `DataPath` in the 1st part? May be they are actually cells? Do you assign strings directly or they are from some variable?

Answer (score 1):

`Dummy` is a cell because you assigned a 3D cell array but are accessing a 2D cell with `Dummy =  Datapath{1,(k-1)*TSRRange+m}`

I don't believe that you can expect to access all cell elements I this way. Instead, use three indices just as you did when creating it.

Comment: This is what I was missing. I didn't assign the third dimension in the second part of the code. Too much coding today....